# Embeddings of Hirzebruch surfaces $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n))$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, line-bundles, embeddings

Let $X_n=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n))$ be the $n-$th Hirzebruch surface. We know that for $d>0$ and higher $k>>0$ the linear system $$\mathcal{L}_{d,k}=|\mathcal{O}_{X_n}(d)\otimes \pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(k)|$$ is very ample, where $\pi:X_n \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ is the projective bundle structure.

Does anybody know an explicit description of the embedding given by $\mathcal{L}_{d,k}$ in an affine patch $U_0 \subset X_n$, where for example $U_0=\mathbb{C}\times (\mathbb{P}^1\setminus [0,1])$ with coordinates $(x,y)$?

I mean an explicit description as in the case of a Veronese embedding, for example.

Comment: A Hirzebruch surface is an example of a rational scroll. Projective embeddings of scrolls are studied in some detail in Chapter 2 of Miles Reid's Chapters on algebraic surfaces https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006.pdf; see around Theorem 2.5.

Comment: @Balazs thank you very much!